# table row is now getting within the boundary

Tags: html, css

I've a table with some rowspans and colspans. here when i'm applying the css the last column is going out of the boundary.

my HTML code is

```
<table class="frame_PD-all">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col class="colnum-1 colname-col1 colwidth-4"></col><col class="colnum-2 colname-col2 colwidth-4"></col><col class="colnum-3 colname-col3 colwidth-7"></col><col class="colnum-4 colname-col4 colwidth-4"></col><col class="colnum-5 colname-col5 colwidth-7"></col><col class="colnum-6 colname-col6 colwidth-10"></col><col class="colnum-7 colname-col7 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-8 colname-col8 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-9 colname-col9 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-10 colname-col10 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-11 colname-col11 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-12 colname-col12 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-13 colname-col13 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-14 colname-col14 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-15 colname-col15 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-16 colname-col16 colwidth-10"></col></colgroup>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">BIL</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">NO. KES</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">NAMA PEMBELI</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">NO. K/P</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">ALAMAT PEMBELI</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH LELONGAN</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH LUPUT</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">HARGA RIZAB</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">HARGA JUALAN</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top" colspan="3">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">DEPOSIT 10% HARGA RIZAB</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top" colspan="3">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">BAKI HARGA BELIAN</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH PENERIMAAN PENYATA AKAUN (S.268(A)) KTN</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">NO RESIT</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">JUMLAH</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">NO RESIT</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">JUMLAH</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

the css applied can be found in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLjFY/), please let me know where am i going wrong. You can see the last column when you extend the html window in fiddle.

I'm missing the border, highlighted int he screenshot and the last column is kicked out of the table. [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cLjFY/3/)**

**html**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">BIL</span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">KES</span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">NAMA PEMBELI</span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">NO. K/P</span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center"><span class="para"><span class="font-style-bold">ALAMAT PEMBELI</span> </span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center"><span class="para"><span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH LELONGAN</span> </span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH LUPUT</span></td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">DEPOSIT 10% HARGA RIZAB</span></td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center"><span class="para"><span class="font-style-bold">BAKI HARGA BELIAN</span></span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH PENERIMAAN PENYATA AKAUN (S.268(A)) KTN</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH</span></td>
    <td align="center"><span class="para"><span class="font-style-bold">NO RESIT</span></span></td>
    <td align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">JUMLAH</span></td>
    <td align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH</span></td>
    <td align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">NO RESIT</span></td>
    <td align="center"><span class="font-style-bold">JUMLAH</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes this is what i wanted, thanks, but can you please let me know where i went wrong?

Comment: which column in specific please?

Comment: Hi @Fags can you please reply, as i've similar issue in other tables as well.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `table-layout: fixed` to your table css....that is missing!!

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLjFY/2/)

do this :

```
table.frame_PD-all {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 0.080em solid;
    margin-top:1em;
    table-layout: fixed; /* added to solve your main problem */
    word-break:break-all;/* added so that words can wrap inside the boundry */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cLjFY/1/)**

**The Code:**

```
<table class="frame_PD-all">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col class="colnum-1 colname-col1 colwidth-4"></col><col class="colnum-2 colname-col2 colwidth-4"></col><col class="colnum-3 colname-col3 colwidth-7"></col><col class="colnum-4 colname-col4 colwidth-4"></col><col class="colnum-5 colname-col5 colwidth-7"></col><col class="colnum-6 colname-col6 colwidth-10"></col><col class="colnum-7 colname-col7 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-8 colname-col8 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-9 colname-col9 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-10 colname-col10 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-11 colname-col11 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-12 colname-col12 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-13 colname-col13 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-14 colname-col14 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-15 colname-col15 colwidth-6"></col><col class="colnum-16 colname-col16 colwidth-10"></col></colgroup>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">BIL</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">NO. KES</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">NAMA PEMBELI</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">NO. K/P</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">ALAMAT PEMBELI</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH LELONGAN</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH LUPUT</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">HARGA RIZAB</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">HARGA JUALAN</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top" colspan="3">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">DEPOSIT 10% HARGA RIZAB</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top" colspan="3">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">BAKI HARGA BELIAN</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <td class="align-center" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH PENERIMAAN PENYATA AKAUN (S.268(A)) KTN</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">NO RESIT</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">JUMLAH</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">TARIKH</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">NO RESIT</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="align-center" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <span class="font-style-bold">JUMLAH</span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para">
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-left" valign="top">
                                    <div class="para"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey sorry for the wrong question. I've updated my question please look into it. Thanks for replying